# Views exposed filters module

Tags: 6, views

My code is working if I am trying to just modify a single form element. 
What do I need to change to checkboxes(multiple elements).

My code is:

```
function custom_filter_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if (isset($form['#parameters'][1]['view'])) {
        $view = $form['#parameters'][1]['view'];
    }
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'views_exposed_form':
            if ($view->name == 'uc_products') {
                custom_filter_range_to_select('sell_price', array(
                         '0,50' => 'Under $50',
                         '50,100' => '$50-$100',
                         '100,150' => '$100-$150',
                         '150,200' => '$150-$200',
                         '200,1000' => 'Over $150',
                ), $form, $form_state);
            }
            break;
    }
}

function custom_filter_range_to_select($field, $value, &$form, &$form_state, $optional = TRUE)
{
    $form[$field]['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
    if ($optional) {
        $value = array_merge(array('All' => 'Any Price'), $value);
    }
    $form[$field]['#options'] = $value;
    unset($form[$field]['min']);
    unset($form[$field]['max']);

    $f = (array)$form_state['input'][$field];
    $array1 = array_pop($f);
    $array1 = array_pop($f);
    $f ? $form[$field]['#value'] = $f : true;
    $form[$field]['#element_validate'] = array('custom_filter_range_validate');
}

function custom_filter_range_validate($element, &$form_state)
{
    $array = (array)$element['#post'][$element['#name']];
    $array1 = array_pop($array);
    $array1 = array_pop($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == 'All') {
            $min = $max = '';
        }
        else {
            list($min, $max) = explode(',', $value);
        }
        $form_state['input'][$element['#name']] = array(
            'min' => $min,
            'max' => $max,
        );
        $form_state['values'][$element['#name']] = array(
            'min' => $min,
            'max' => $max,
        );
    }
}
```